# How to place OCO order with E*Trade API

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, etrade-api

Is it possible to place an OCO (One Cancels Other) from the E*Trade Equity API?

Here it lists these order types under Placing an Equity Order

```
MARKET
LIMIT
STOP
STOP_LIMIT
MARKET_ON_CLOSE
```

https://us.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getDetail?contentId=99c70918-5477-486f-92a7-af93d21e8702

I don't see One Cancels Other.

However, in the List Orders API, I see information about OCO orders.

https://us.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getDetail?contentUri=V0_Documentation-OrderAPI-ListOrders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Etrade, they do not support OCO orders :(

```
Sent: December 29, 2017 2:13 PM ET

Thank you for your message regarding the E*TRADE API.

The E*TRADE API does support placing advanced order such as OCO orders.
The E*TRADE API will return a list of all open orders including advanced order 
placed on the website or E*TRADE Pro.
```

Answer (score 0):

Under order look for the tab "conditional" once you open that there is a list of options to choose from. One triggers all or One cancels other.